# Cassandra Timestamp data type

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

This is my Database Structure

```
CREATE TABLE stack (
    id UUID,
    entrytime TIMESTAMP,
    name TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, entrytime)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( entrytime DESC );
```

And when I use the Insert statement as.

```
INSERT INTO stack ( id, entrytime, name )
VALUES ( now(), toTimestamp( now() ), 'Nik' );
```

But it stores the entry time column as `2018-01-15 08:29:58.174000+0000`

I want to remove the extra precision that Cassandra provides.
I know this has to do something with the `cqlshrc.sample` file but I am not able to do it.

Can anyone help me out here?

This is a portion of my cqlshrc file

```
[ui]
;; Whether or not to display query results with colors
; color = on

;; Used for displaying timestamps (and reading them with COPY)
time_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

;; Display timezone
;timezone = Etc/UTC
```

Now when I run my cql shell then following error occurs.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/www/html/cassandra/apache-cassandra-
   3.11.1/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2434, in <module>
     main(*read_options(sys.argv[1:], os.environ))
   File "/var/www/html/cassandra/apache-cassandra-
   3.11.1/bin/cqlsh.py", line 2211, in read_options
     configs.read(CONFIG_FILE)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 305, in read
     self._read(fp, filename)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 512, in _read
      raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
   ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
    file: /home/ubuntu/.cassandra/cqlshrc, line: 1
```

'\xef\xbb\xbf; Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one\n'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert into `~/.cassandra/cqlshrc` file, into `[ui]` section following line (this is for 3.x):

```
time_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z
```

Description of `%` fields you can find [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

P.S. I've modified the answer because the `datetimeformat` is used only in `COPY FROM`'s options, not in the `cqlshrc`...

Comment: Do I have to create a .cassandra folder into the directory where my Cassandra is installed?

Comment: No, the `~/` means your home directory - see documentation for details: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshUsingCqlshrc.html

Comment: my cqlshrc.sample file is in  ~/ .cassandra/bin so if i do changes in that file then paste that file into my home directory where my cassandra is installed so would it work?

Comment: You need to copy `conf/cqlshrc.sample` as `~/.cassandra/.cqlshrc`. Please note that I changed the answer because of bug in documentation - the configuration parameter is really called `time_format`.

Comment: Is it working for you because it's not working for me? My cassandra is running on AWS server so I think I don't need to restart it again?

Comment: Works for me just fine: with default format I get `2018-03-06 14:41:11.045000+0000`, with `time_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z` I get `2018-03-06 14:41:11+0000`

Comment: What I am doing is I am copying the cqlshrc.sample file from my conf folder then I copied it inside my cassandra folder and rename it to cqlshrc and then does the following changes. Is it all? or do I need to add something more? and can you provide me ur cqlshrc file with the new time_format in case I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: It should be enough. - my config that I did use in the example is just 2 lines: `[ui]` section & `time_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z`

Comment: Just one more thing. After doing all of this did you restart your cassandra again?

Comment: I have updated my question can you look whether my changes are correct or not?

Comment: Looks ok for me

Comment: I have updated my question again can you please look for that error?

Comment: Please check that you didn't edit this file using plain text editor, not the editor that put Under code marker at begin of file

Comment: I know its against the stack overflow policy but I wanted to thankyou you helped my alot with this problem of mine and now it's done successfully.