# How to configure CQL timestamp to %d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S%z

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, cql

I use Cassandra on Windows 10 Pro. I have created the following table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE testee (
               serialno int,
               changeDate timestamp,
               value text,
               devicename text,
               PRIMARY KEY ((serialno, changeDate), changeDate)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (changeID DESC);
```

The given date format (timestamp) is:
%d-% m-%-Y% H:%M:%S%z

The Cassandra default timestamp is:
%Y-% m-%-d% H:%M:%S%z

For the conversion of the date format I have followed the instructions of Datastax:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshUsingCqlshrc.html

Now the cqlshrc file is under:

> C:\Users\tlq\ .cassandra\cqlshrc

According to this solved question [Cassandra Timestamp data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276297/cassandra-timestamp-data-type), 'time_format' must be inserted in the [ui] section of the cqlshrc file. I did this:

```
[ui]

;; Used for displaying timestamps (and reading them with COPY)
datetimeformat = %d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S%z

;;Used for used displaying timestamps generell

time_format = %d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S%z
```

By using the insert command:

```
INSERT INTO foo(serialno, changedate, devicename) VALUES(2,'07-12-2011 13:56:20','fooname',34);
```

The following message still appears

> InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unable to >coerce '07-12-2014 13:56:20' to a formatted date (long)"

Comment: Do you also start cqlsh with CQLSHRC="C:\Users\tlq\ .cassandra\cqlshrc"? I'm not sure how well this works on Windows but perhaps you need to escape some characters. Basically what I'm asking is: are you sure your cqlshrc file is used? Could you add some faulty configuration for host or port to verify the file is used.

Comment: I followed your advice by trying a wrong port (9041) and host (127.0.0.2). The cqlshrc seems to be in the right place:

Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.2': error (10061, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.2', 9041)] Last error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ")}}

Comment: what are you using to insert it from? In most languages trivial to convert dates to a timestamp (long) which gets rid of a lot of ambiguity.

Comment: We used sql: SELECT convert(datetime, '22-10-2013 20:44:11', 120) -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss(24h)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options that you specify in the `cqlshrc` file is for diplaying of data, not for input strings.  Cassandra accepts data in following formats, described in [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_reference/refDateTimeFormats.html):

> yyyy-mm-dd[(T| )HH:MM:SS[.fff]][(+|-)NNNN]

So you need to specify date in correct order: year-month-day...

P.S. When you don't specify the timezone, it's taken from client's configuration - you need to specify your default timezone by adding the `timezone` parameter to `cqlshrc` file (same `[ui]` section), like this:

```
timezone = Etc/UTC
```

See also [documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/cqlsh.html) that talks about installing optional packages like `pytz`.